How to fetch records having difference of 5 minutes or less | Oracle
I am currently stuck with this approch not getting how do i need to minus with current timestamp and find all records which as a difference of 5 minutes or less
My table
create table demo ( id number, modified_date timestamp(6)  );
insert into demo values(1,to_timestamp('10-MAY-19 07.14.15.066000000 AM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'));   
insert into demo values(5,to_timestamp('10-MAY-19 07.16.11.064000000 AM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'));    
insert into demo values(3,to_timestamp('10-MAY-19 07.15.13.062000000 AM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'));
insert into demo values(12,to_timestamp('10-MAY-19 07.18.10.056000000 AM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'));
insert into demo values(14,to_timestamp('10-MAY-19 07.20.09.046000000 AM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'));

Data in table
id  modified_date 
1   10-MAY-19 07.14.15.066000000 AM
5   10-MAY-19 07.16.11.064000000 AM
3   10-MAY-19 07.15.13.062000000 AM
12  10-MAY-19 07.18.10.056000000 AM
14  10-MAY-19 07.20.09.046000000 AM

My query does not give in minutes
select modified_date - current_timestamp  as dt_minutes from demo;
Expected : Need record as a difference of 5 minutes or less with current_timestamp
id  modified_date                    date_differenence    
1   10-MAY-19 07.14.15.066000000 AM  modified_date - current_timestamp ( in minutes )
5   10-MAY-19 07.16.11.064000000 AM  modified_date - current_timestamp ( in minutes )
3   10-MAY-19 07.15.13.062000000 AM  modified_date - current_timestamp ( in minutes )
12  10-MAY-19 07.18.10.056000000 AM  modified_date - current_timestamp ( in minutes )
14  10-MAY-19 07.20.09.046000000 AM  modified_date - current_timestamp ( in minutes )

Note:
NLS_LANGUAGE = 'AMERICAN'
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR'
NLS_CALENDAR ='GREGORIAN'


The sample data in your question is all from May 2019; this month is July 2024 and none of your rows are going to be within 5 minutes of the current date (they aren't even within 5 years). Please explain, in English (not code), what the logic is that you are expecting to implement and what is the expected output for your sample data?

Use an INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND:
SELECT id,
       modified_date,
       current_date,
       modified_date - current_timestamp AS interval_difference,
       EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM modified_date - current_timestamp) AS minutes_difference
FROM   demo
WHERE  modified_date BETWEEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '5' MINUTE
                         AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '5' MINUTE;

Use ABS(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM current_date - modified_date)) if you are not worried about the sign.
Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE demo (
  id NUMBER,
  modified_date TIMESTAMP(6)
);

INSERT INTO demo (id, modified_date)
  SELECT 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '10' MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '5:01' MINUTE TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '5:00' MINUTE TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '4:59' MINUTE TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '0' MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '4:59' MINUTE TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '5:01' MINUTE TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '5' YEAR FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



ID
MODIFIED_DATE
CURRENT_DATE
INTERVAL_DIFFERENCE
MINUTES_DIFFERENCE




3
2024-07-07 15:42:27.262701
2024-07-07 15:37:27
+000000000 00:04:59.975026
4


4
2024-07-07 15:42:26.262701
2024-07-07 15:37:27
+000000000 00:04:58.975026
4


5
2024-07-07 15:37:27.262701
2024-07-07 15:37:27
-000000000 00:00:00.024974
0


6
2024-07-07 15:32:28.262701
2024-07-07 15:37:27
-000000000 00:04:59.024974
-4



fiddle

I tried in different way below is my answer. Thank you for your answers. Help me in correcting my below solution if it is wrong.

Seems like the query is not able to fetch records for me.  Can you check question again I have updated few more details about my system NLS in notes . Is that the issue causing not able to get any reocrds.

could you help me to resolve it

I tried it in this way and it worked. In case any issue in mu query. Kindly help me with correcting it along with explanation.
SELECT
    id,
    modified_date,
    EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CAST(current_timestamp AS TIMESTAMP))                                                         AS cur_minutes,
    EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CAST(modified_date AS TIMESTAMP))                                                             AS mod_minutes,
    EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CAST(current_timestamp AS TIMESTAMP)) - EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CAST(modified_date AS TIMESTAMP)) AS min_diff
FROM
    demo
WHERE
    modified_date > current_timestamp - INTERVAL '5' MINUTE;


This is wrong as if the current time is 12:03:00 and the modified time is 11:59:00 then 3 - 59 = -56 when the actual difference is 4 minutes. You need to extract the minutes from the interval difference (after subtracting) and not from the from the times (before subtracting). I have updated my answer.
